# How do I make a field referenced to appear in the active admin view on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have two models, one users and one account managers, The users table has an account managers reference field.

However, when I select the users, all there information is listed except the user's account manager.

How do I make the account manager appear when I click the Users link in active admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app/admin you add

```
permit_params :account_manager
```

and in the index you add :

```
index do 
 column :account_manager do |a|
  a.account_manager_for_user
 end
```

where account_manager_for_user is a method that returns the account manager in the user model:

```
def account_manager_for_user
 self.account_manager
end
```